# Does iis keep track of when last it was reset

Tags: iis

I would like to know when iis was last restarted. 
Does IIS keep a log of this and where can I find this log?

Thank you

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1. Open Event viewer, navigate to "Windows Logs" -> "System"
2. on the right "Actions" pane, select "filter Current Log..."
3. Under "Event Sources:" select or type "IIS-IISReset"
4. hit ok

Results in event viewer should now just show you IIS Resets

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer instead of the above.

Comment: if it's empty, what do we need to do?

Answer (score 9):

Like for other Windows services, the Service Control Manager (SCM) keeps track of service restarts on the **System Log** of the machine. Please take a look at the Event Viewer to see them.

Comment: For those finding this question via google,  could you explain what to look for and where to look for it in event viewer?

Comment: This answer isn't specific enough.  What logs specifically do I look for.  How do I filter for them?

Comment: Windows Logs -> System